# email - how to add and preserve an ID to email message

Tags: php, email, imap

My app sends emails to users and now I'm receiving their responses via PHP-IMAP.

The problem is on how to identify the original message on incoming email.

I tried adding a hidden ID into body this way:

```
<!--[id]{{ $request->id }}[/id]-->
<html lang="en-US" data-id="{{$request->id}}">
```

It's being sent fine but when the users sends reply, those tags are not present in message body.

Is there any tag or tricky so I can persist a parameter in message body for reply messages?

Comment: why not use the Message-ID email header

Comment: I tried but when the user reply the email it comes with another ID.

Comment: The reply should have In-Reply-To header with the old message id

Comment: Or use unique from addresses.